# auto zoom in n out CSS (apple-like slideshow effect)

Tags: html, css

I like pretty much the slow auto zoom in and out effect on that site : http://watchingtheworldcup.com/ for banner images such as the very top one. 
I tired to replicate it, by looking at developer tools wihtin browser, but have some trouble implementing it as in developper tool some mentions are stroked etc.

here is my html :

```
 <div class="row">  
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <a href="#">
             <article class="article_container">
                 <img class="article_image_hompage5" src="#">       
                 <h2 class="article_title_hompage3"> a favourite thai soup</h2>     
             </article>
         </a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and my css for the image :

```
.article_image_hompage5{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:15px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Can someone help with with finding the right css settings ? 
cheers,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use css animation you can get the similar result.

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    to {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes zoom {
   from {
        transform: scale(1,1);
   }
   to {
        transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
   }
}


img {
    -webkit-animation: zoom 50s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: zoom 50s;
}
```

```html
<img alt="" src="http://watchingtheworldcup.com/photos/worldcup1.jpg" />
```

Comment: can you please highlight how do I embed those in my css ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp for your case, change img {... to .article_image_hompage5 {

Comment: thx max li, works well. For future (beginners) visitors, just a precision, the picture needs to be framed within a div container to avoid overflow

Comment: last question , would you know how to make it a "loop" event ?

Comment: you can add infinite inside animation:  -webkit-animation: zoom 50s infinite;

Comment: Hey max li if you are still here... "infinite"  works well, tough currently at the end of animation zoom resume from starting state, (if you know what I mean) would you know how to make it gently zoom out again, once zoom in is over ?

Comment: i have 3 image tag with different images how can we do the same zoom showing one after one in few seconds any suggestion please

Comment: Just a note here, beware of using this on large images, it's kind of heavy (in my case i had blur too so it got even worse).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to also zoom out you need to define the the milestones in your keyframes as such:

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoominout {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `css transform:scale();`

like:

JavaScript:

```js
window.onload=function(){
$("#content").fadeOut(4000);
    $("#background").addClass("zoom");
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("#background").removeClass("zoom");
    },5000);
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
#background{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:url("http://watchingtheworldcup.com/photos/worldcup1.jpg") center center no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
display:inline-block;
    z-index:2;
    transition:all ease 4.1s;
   /* transform:scale(1,1);*/
}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:3;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:50px;
}
.zoom{
    transform:scale(1.2,1.2);
}

HTML:
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background">    
</div>
<div id="content">
    <center><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        Watching...
    </center>
</div>
```